# Wildfly 12 error in datasource

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly, datasource

I'm trying to create a simple datasource in Wildfly 12 in order to connect a mysql database to a Java WEB Application.

I have tried 2 options:

1. Modify the standalone-full.xml to add the datasource like this:

   ```
   <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MyDS" pool-name="MyDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
               <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabaseName</connection-url>
               <driver>mysql</driver>
               <pool>
                   <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                   <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
               </pool>
               <security>
                   <user-name>myuser</user-name>
                   <password>mypassword</password>
               </security>
           </datasource>
           <drivers>
               <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                   <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
               </driver>
           </drivers>
   ```

   2. Add the datasource using the admin console

I'm creating a Connection using the datasource without problems:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext(), envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        DataSource ds = (DataSource) envCtx.lookup("jdbc/MyDS");
        this.connection = ds.getConnection();
```

The Java Connection works without errors but when I create a servlet to query my database, I got an exception like this:

"Table "user" not found; SQL statement: Select * from user where username = 'myusername'"

I have run some tests and I could notice that Java is connected to the database but not to the specific schema, I run a query like "SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL" and the result is "TEST". So I guess that the database name param in the URL connection is not working properly.

How can I solve this problem? I haven't found any additional param to specify the database name in the datasource.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after having tried some modifications, I realized that I had to put the next code in the web.xml file:

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDS/<res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/MyDatabaseName</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

This solved the problem.